# Converting RTF file to PDF in c#

Tags: c#

I need to provide a functionality to convert a RTF/WORD file to PDF and send it as attachment in an email, for this i tried the code as shown below:

```
    // Create a new Microsoft Word application object
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

    // C# doesn't have optional arguments so we'll need a dummy value
    object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    Document doc;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConvertToPDF("test.doc");
    }

    void ConvertToPDF(string sFileName)
    {
        // Create a new Microsoft Word application object
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        // C# doesn't have optional arguments so we'll need a dummy value
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        Document doc;
        try
        {
            word.Visible = false;
            word.ScreenUpdating = false;

            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(".") + "\\TempDoc");
            FileInfo[] wordFile = dirInfo.GetFiles(sFileName);

            if (wordFile.Length > 0)
            {
                Object filename = (Object)wordFile[0].FullName;

                // Use the dummy value as a placeholder for optional arguments
                doc = word.Documents.Open2000(ref filename, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                doc.Activate();

                object outputFileName = wordFile[0].FullName.Replace(".doc", "");
                object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;

                // Save document into PDF Formats
                doc.SaveAs2000(ref outputFileName, ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close the Word document, but leave the Word application open.
            // doc has to be cast to type _Document so that it will find the
            // correct Close method.
            doc = null;

            // word has to be cast to type _Application so that it will find
            // the correct Quit method.
            word = null;
        }

    }
```

But it gives error on 
doc.SaveAs2000(ref outputFileName, ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
statement.

This may have reason that we have Microsoft Office 2007 and in this, there is not any option to save as PDF file. While in Microsoft Office 2010 it has that option so this code may work when Microsoft Office 2010 is installed on server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert an RTF file to a pdf file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853314/how-can-i-convert-an-rtf-file-to-a-pdf-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does work in 2010. I've used it recently but I believe there is a patch for 2007 that add the save as PDF functionality too

Maybe try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412305(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I am on my way to try this also. Thank you very much.

Comment: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005....... i got this error in my application and before this i made a demo project for converting docx to pdf. Do you have any knowledge about thi..??

Answer (score 0):

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        appWord.Visible = false;

        //object oMissing = Type.Missing;
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        // Declare variables for the Document.ExportAsFixedFormat method parameters.
        bool paramOpenAfterExport = false;
        Office.WdExportOptimizeFor paramExportOptimizeFor =
        Office.WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen;
        Office.WdExportRange paramExportRange = Office.WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument;
        int paramStartPage = 0;
        int paramEndPage = 0;
        Office.WdExportItem paramExportItem = Office.WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentWithMarkup; //This is 
        //the key to keep track changes markup;
        bool paramIncludeDocProps = true;
        bool paramKeepIRM = true;
        Office.WdExportCreateBookmarks paramCreateBookmarks =
                    Office.WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateWordBookmarks;
        bool paramDocStructureTags = true;
        bool paramBitmapMissingFonts = true;
        bool paramUseISO19005_1 = false;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(fileToProcess);

        wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(tempPDFFilePath, Office.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, paramOpenAfterExport, paramExportOptimizeFor, paramExportRange, paramStartPage, paramEndPage, paramExportItem,
        paramIncludeDocProps, paramKeepIRM, paramCreateBookmarks, paramDocStructureTags, paramBitmapMissingFonts, paramUseISO19005_1, ref oMissing);

        ((Office._Document)wordDocument).Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        ((Office._Application)appWord).Quit(false);
```

First need to add Microsoft.Office.Interop.dll from nugget package. Add .rft orginal file as fileToProcess and in tempFilePath add location path where you need to save converted pdf file.

Comment: This solution is also use to convert Text file to pdf in c#