# How to convert rtf or docx to PDF server-side (without having OpenType fonts rasterized or substituted)

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts

does anyone know of a tool that permits rtf/doc/docx conversion to pdf from C# ?
These documents contain all sorts of fonts (TrueType or OpenType), and I am looking for a tool that will not rasterize the OpenTypes ones and render them rather accurately.

Many thanks in advance for any pointers !

Comment: You know about itextsharp? [Disclaimer: I havent used it myself, so not sure if it meets your exact requirements, just providing you hint here really]

Comment: Why a down vote? This is a legit question.

Comment: @PiotrJustyna I didn't downvote it, but this question lacks research effort. Franklin, please update if you have already tried any library/fx

Comment: Stack overflow is neither your research assistant nor your recommendation engine. What have you tried?

Comment: possible dupliate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257827/converting-rtf-file-to-pdf-in-c-sharp

Comment: There are plenty of third party things out there. I have tried several solutions myself. So the question is pretty much about fonts issues largely met with OpenType fonts, and targeted at anyone who has found a solution to not have fonts bitmapped//substituted when using non standard OpenType fonts.

Comment: @Colin, not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx)

It works server side and does not require Office Automation.

I've used it in a commercial project and it works really good. But it's a commercial component, so you need to pay for a license (which is not that cheap)

EDIT
please have a look at this [thread](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/431265/embedded-fonts-in-aspose.words.aspx) in the Aspose forum

Comment: It's a good component and I am preferring it also. But as I remember it requires installed fonts on server , or otherwise fonts either will be substituted or rasterized.

Comment: The question is, will it successfully import OpenType and TrueType fonts ? Otherwise it's the same Microsoft issue over and over again.

Comment: Well, it's not dead accurate, but at least not all OpenType fonts are rasterized with it...

Answer (score 0):

I've used iTextSharp myself in a C# project recently, and it worked pretty well. 
Unfortunately, I'm not able to give you any example, as that would make a huge post (and the code is pretty confidential) :)

But here's the link to their site, if that helps:

http://itextpdf.com/

Hope this fits your needs!

Comment: It seems itextsharp is not able to convert rtf and doc/docx to pdf at the moment. Or is it ?

Comment: What you can do is convert the rtf & doc(x) files to HTML first, and then to PDF. That's one way to do it, which can be done using iTextSharp.